# How to know which residues belong to the variable or constant regions of a Fab (fragment antibody)?

Tags: sequence-analysis, antibody

I have a fragment of antibody (Fab) structure, and I know its amino acid sequences of its heavy chain and light chain. As each chain of Fab can be divided into variable and constant regions, how can I know which residues belong to the variable or constant regions?

I can of course look at its 3-D structure in `pymol`, but it is difficult to know the belonging of residues between the variable and constant regions.

[image]

[This link](http://www.bioinf.org.uk/abs/#cdrid) clearly shows how to identify the CDR regions based on its amino acid sequence. Is there a similar way to differentiate variable and constant regions?

Comment: The CDR is the variable region. I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: The CDR is only part of the variable region, i.e. the CDR is only part of the VH, VL. Could you please remove the downvote? [Complementarity-determining regions (CDRs) are part of the variable chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity-determining_region)

Comment: I stand corrected. I did not downvote, but I will upvote.

Comment: thank you! It is really frustrating to be downvoted without knowing the reason....